# Laravel Many-To-Many sync() on multiple columns

Tags: laravel, eloquent, synchronization, many-to-many

I'm trying to do the following:

I have Targets model;
I have Fields model;
These two are a many-to-many relation through a pivot table;
I want to be able to use a multi-column unique or primary and use sync() to update the "amount" column on pivot table.

See the images.

Targets table:

[image]

Fields table:

[image]

Pivot table (ideally):

[image]

As you can see on the pivot table, theres "year" and "month" and I only need to be able to "sync" or update the amount for that particular year/month for a particular field.

When I do this with sync() (don't mind the "UserTarget::". Assume it's "Target::" for simplification):

[image]

it updates the pivot table with the LAST array item and I get this:

[image]

but it must be like this:

[image]

My Target model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\TargetField;

class Target extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'targets';

    public function fields()
    {
        // return $this->belongsToMany(
        //     RelatedModel, 
        //     pivot_table_name, 
        //     foreign_key_of_current_model_in_pivot_table, 
        //     foreign_key_of_other_model_in_pivot_table
        // );

        return $this->belongsToMany(
                'App\Models\Field',
                'target_field',
                'user_target_id',
                'user_target_field_id'
            )->withPivot(['year', 'month', 'amount', 'user_id']);
    }

}
```

Field model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Field extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'fields';

    public function targets()
    {
        // return $this->belongsToMany(
        //     RelatedModel, 
        //     pivot_table_name, 
        //     foreign_key_of_current_model_in_pivot_table, 
        //     foreign_key_of_other_model_in_pivot_table
        // );

        return $this->belongsToMany(
                'App\Models\Target',
                'target_field',
                'user_target_field_id',
                'user_target_id'
            )->withPivot(['year', 'month', 'amount', 'user_id']);
    }

}
```

I'm doing this in the pivot model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TargetField extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    // pivot table to get user target fields (many to many)
    protected $table = 'target_field';

    public $incrementing = false;

    protected $primaryKey = ['user_target_id','user_target_field_id','user_id','year','month'];

    protected $fillable = ['user_target_id','user_target_field_id','user_id','year','month'];

    /**
     * Set the keys for a save update query.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    protected function setKeysForSaveQuery($query)
    {
        $keys = $this->getKeyName();
        if(!is_array($keys)){
            return parent::setKeysForSaveQuery($query);
        }

        foreach($keys as $keyName){
            $query->where($keyName, '=', $this->getKeyForSaveQuery($keyName));
        }

        return $query;
    }

    /**
     * Get the primary key value for a save query.
     *
     * @param mixed $keyName
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function getKeyForSaveQuery($keyName = null)
    {
        if(is_null($keyName)){
            $keyName = $this->getKeyName();
        }

        if (isset($this->original[$keyName])) {
            return $this->original[$keyName];
        }

        return $this->getAttribute($keyName);
    }

}
```

Do you have any idea or suggestion on what I might be doing wrong?

So basically I want to be able to save/update multiple rows on the pivot table (years, months, user_id) which have different values from the "amount" column.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use [newPivotQuery](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Concerns/InteractsWithPivotTable.html#method_newPivotQuery) that Create a new query builder for the pivot table.

```
$userTaraget=UserTarget::find(1);
// first delete old rows:
$userTaraget->Fields()->newPivotQuery()->where('user_id',188)->delete();
// then: insert new ones:
$userTaraget->Fields()->newPivotQuery()->saveMany([['year'=>2021, 'month'=>3, 'amount'=>5, 'user_id'=>188],
['year'=>2020, ....]);
```